# Unable ro run "rake db:schema:dump" and getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, mysql2

I am trying to start database and still learining ruby on rails. But in this step I've got an error when running following code in `cmd`.

I have installed `mysql2` and it is appeared in gem list. I put `database.yml` file in the tutorial sample files to my working folder. Still got the error. And installed all `mysql2` again. installed bundle again.

Note: I'm using Windows 8.1 64 Bit.

```
C:\Users\Thilanka\myapp>rake db:schema:dump
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not load
ed. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum
 required by ActiveRecord).

Gem::LoadError: mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.

Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have the following line in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Run `bundle install` once you added that line to your `Gemfile`.

You might want to read the [install notes for Windows](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#windows) if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how Windows behave in this case but from my experience (still learning RoR and I'm in the middle of a migration between sqlite and mysql).
The first thing I did was install mysql on my computer, then as @spickermann said declare the gem in the Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

For the error you show (`Gem::LoadError: mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.`) it seems that you missed the Gemfile step.